# Why "0Looking" and new line is appended while copying all raw text from any github file while using Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, github, copy-paste

For example if you copy the text of this [file](https://github.com/google/grumpy/blob/master/README.md) and click on `raw` button, you will see 0Looking and new line appended to your clipboard. You should copy using `Ctrl/Cmd + A` and `Ctrl/Cmd + C` and then paste using `Ctrl/Cmd + V`

Is there a way to avoid this?
I am using Mac, is this limited to Mac only? Can anyone confirm it?

An example is [this one](https://s8.postimg.org/h8xeb7j0l/Screen_Shot_2017_03_13_at_10_44_56_AM.png)

**Edit:**

Doesn't happen on Firefox and Safari while copy pasting. Only on Google chrome.

[Here is the video of the bug](https://youtu.be/nXkvEYOv-tE)

Thanks

Comment: `"No results found for '0Looking'` -- Atom Editor

Comment: @cricket_007 I am seeing this https://s8.postimg.org/h8xeb7j0l/Screen_Shot_2017_03_13_at_10_44_56_AM.png  when I paste after copying and pasting all from raw file on github. Is there a confusion here? I am using chrome.

Comment: Atom Editor uses the latest Chromium build. I'm not seeing it

Comment: Where are you pasting into Chrome??

Comment: I am not pasting into Chrome, I am pasting in text editor. I am using Chrome to access the url and do `Cmd + A` and `Cmd + C` and then paste using `Cmd + V`.

Comment: Me too. Not seeing it. Just upgraded my Chrome too...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snfzp.png

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited my question to reproduce the bug, if you go to https://github.com/google/grumpy/blob/master/README.md then click on `raw` button and then do copy paste, you will see it.

Comment: Nope. Incognito Mode didn't do it either.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your patience. I just edited the question with the video(https://youtu.be/nXkvEYOv-tE), describing the bug.

Comment: I think it's a bug with your computer's clipboard, sorry. Can't reproduce